# Sneat theme HTML - i can't configure config.js

Tags: css, user-interface, themes

I just started using Sneat Theme for my project, all good until I wanted to change the color scheme for all the project. From my understanding i have to use config.js for the colors and everything, but it seems that this is not working in my case.

I've included everything in my project as follow

Config#
Use config.js to configure TemplateCustomizer settings application-wide by modifying global variables.

Use helpers.js and template-customizer.js scripts in the  section.
Use config.js file to Initialize the TemplateCustomizer plugin. It's important to initialize the plugin in the  section
Add template-customizer-core-css and template-customizer-theme-css classes to core and theme-* stylesheets.

This is from the documentation. [documentation](https://demos.themeselection.com/sneat-bootstrap-html-admin-template/documentation/config.html)

Even after all the modification... my color scheme is not changing for the entire project.

Can you help me with this one? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the config.js file of the sneat theme to change colors. You can check Customize SASS [documentation](https://demos.themeselection.com/sneat-bootstrap-html-admin-template/documentation/customization-sass.html#customizing-sass)

To Change the primary color, follow the documentation FAQs [here](https://demos.themeselection.com/sneat-bootstrap-html-admin-template/documentation/customization-sass.html#change-primary-color)

That will change the entire theme colors :)

To customize the template, with custom config options, please follow the documentation [here](https://demos.themeselection.com/sneat-bootstrap-html-admin-template/documentation/config.html) and find configuration settings [here](https://demos.themeselection.com/sneat-bootstrap-html-admin-template/documentation/config.html#template-customizer-settings)

Let me know how it works for you!!

Regards